# How to load app-engine hosted HTML file in Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cordova, server-error

I want to load an app-engine deployed application file in Android without using Android's `WebView`. When I used the following code in PhoneGap, it shows the message, **connection to the server was unsuccessful.**

Code:

```
public class HelloCordovaActivity extends DroidGap {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("http://5.appid.appspot.com/");
  }
```

Or suggest an alternate method to load an explicitly hosted file in app engine using Phonegap.

Comment: Did you enable network permissions in the Manifest of your Android app?

Comment: @ systempuntoout yes, it was not due to TimeoutValue.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [here](http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/04/solving-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-error-in-androidphonegap/), the reported error could be caused by a Timeout issue.

I would try to add this call just above the `loadUrl` statement:

`super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);`